# Trying to call SwiftUI library CodeScannerView on UIKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I was using the CodeScannerView library with SwiftUI successfully.

I was using the example from the website

https://github.com/twostraws/CodeScanner

This is the code:

```
    // more code
    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingScanner) {
        CodeScannerView(codeTypes: [.qr, .code128]) { response in
            if case let .success(result) = response {
                scannedCode = result.string
                codigoBarra = scannedCode!
                print("my scannedCode: \(String(describing: scannedCode))")
                isPresentingScanner = false
            }
        }
    }
```

It works perfectly.

But now I want to use the library on UIKit, is it possible to use this library with UIKit?

Comment: Use `UIHostingController`

Comment: The use of UIHostingController creates an entire new view, and I already had a complex UIKit that I only want to add one element from SwiftUI.

Comment: That is the only way to interface with From UIKit to SwiftUI. You just `present(hostingController)` to show in a modal